# Find attributes in an object

Tags: templating

I have a craft project which I've inherited and I'm trying to make some minor changes. I don't know PHP, Craft, or Twig very well so forgive me if this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). This website is a company website and has pages for projects, jobs, case studies etc.

Basically, I have something called an `entry` in the templates and this has attributes like `.title`, `.offerings` etc. This *entry* is a project and if I view the text in the admin interface, I can see some fields there. There are parts of the code that look like this

```
  {% set projectDescription = entry.title%}
```

My question is, how do I know what are the attributes that `entry` has so that I can pull it out and display it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The `entry` variable is an instance of [`craft\elements\Entry`](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-elements-entry.html). Most of the attributes you are going to be interested in are either properties of the class or customf fields.

### Class properties

All entries have properties like a the `title`, `id`, `postDate`, `slug`, `authorId`, etc. You can find them in the [class reference for the Entry class](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-elements-entry.html). Check out the [base Element class](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-base-element.html) as well – all element types (entries, categories, assets, etc) inherit from it.

### Custom fields

Custom fields are the fields you have defined in your Craft installation and added to the entry's [Entry type](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/entries.html#entry-types). You can check the entry type in Settings -> Sections -> [Name of the section] -> Tab "Entry Types" -> [Name of the Entry type].

If you're not sure which section or entry type your entry has, you can find out like this:

```twig
{% dd [entry.section.name, entry.type.name] %}
```

You can also display field handles in the entry edit form. Go to your account preferences and check the option *Show field handles in edit forms *. Then go to edit the entry – the field handles will be displayed in the upper right of each field.

Finally, here's a handy oneliner to get an array of custom field handles for an entry:

```twig
{% dd entry.getFieldLayout().getFields()|column('handle') %}
```

Further reading: [How to check for available fields for an entry](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/37760/11705)